# android app set control value of Fragment ParcelableArrayList

Tags: android, fragment, parcelable, fragmentstatepageradapter

Help me Everyone,

I can get a ParcelableArrayList of Fragment, but cannot get value of Control in `onCreateView()`

How to set value to Control object?

```
public static class ArrayListFragment extends Fragment
{

    int mNum;
    int mSEQ;
    String mHAWB;
    String mMAWB;

    /**
     * Create a new instance of CountingFragment, providing "num" as an
     * argument.
     */
    static ArrayListFragment newInstance(ArrayList<Course> courselist)
    {

        //NUM_ITEMS = courselist.size();

        ArrayListFragment f = new ArrayListFragment();

        //Bundle args = new Bundle();
        //args.putInt("num", num);
        //f.setArguments(args);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

        //bundle.putParcelable("CourseList", (Parcelable) courselist);
        bundle.putParcelableArrayList("CourseList", courselist);
        f.setArguments(bundle);

        return f;
    }

    /**
     * When creating, retrieve this instance's number from its arguments.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //mNum = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getInt("num") : 1;
        courselist = getArguments().getParcelableArrayList("CourseList");

        //mHAWB = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getString("HAWB") : "String";
        //mMAWB = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getString("MAWB") : "String";

    }

    /**
     * The Fragment's UI is just a simple text view showing its instance
     * number.
     */
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page, container, false);
        TextView tvSEQ = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.SEQ);
        TextView tvHAWB = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.HAWB);
        TextView tvMAWB = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.MAWB);
        tvSEQ.setText(mSEQ);
        tvHAWB.setText(mHAWB);
        tvMAWB.setText(mMAWB);
        return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: Move this line `courselist = getArguments().getParcelableArrayList("CourseList");` to `onCreateView()` or `onActivityCreated()` method.

Comment: what can i do after moving  ?

Comment: @Jacky: nothing to do. just move it inside onCreateView method

Comment: i want set value in control of View(like TextView,EditView....) ? 
how can i do with this?
like this ->
mHAWB = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getString("HAWB") : "String";